# C# Refactor to Recursive Method

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to take this basic iterative method and make it recursive. Not having much luck. I've tried something like this so far.

My goal is the outer most loop to return the "title" no matter where in the children the Id is identified.

**Attempt:**

```cs
private string Fn( List<WorkflowHierarchy.Result> results, string id, string title )
{
  foreach (var result in results)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
      title = result.title;
    }
    
    if (result.id == id)
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      if (result.children != null && result.children.page.results.Any())
      {
        Fn(result.children.page.results, id, title);
      }
      else
      {
        title = null;
      }
    }
  }

  return title;
}
```

**Working non recursive method:**

```cs
private string GetParent(WorkflowHierarchy.Rootobject workFlowHierarchy, string id)
{
  var parent = string.Empty;
  foreach (var item in workFlowHierarchy.results)
  {
    if (item.id == id)
    {
      parent = item.title;
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      if (item.children != null)
      {
        foreach (var item2 in item.children.page.results)
        {
          if (item2.id == id)
          {
            parent = item.title;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            if (item2.children != null)
            {
              foreach (var item3 in item2.children.page.results)
              {
                if (item3.id == id)
                {
                  parent = item.title;
                  break;
                }
                else
                {
                  if (item3.children != null)
                  {
                    foreach (var item4 in item3.children.page.results)
                    {
                      if (item4.id == id)
                      {
                        parent = item.title;
                        break;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        if (item4.children != null)
                        {
                          foreach (var item5 in item4.children.page.results)
                          {
                            if (item5.id == id)
                            {
                              parent = item.title;
                              break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              if (item5.children != null)
                              {
                                foreach (var item6 in item5.children.page.results)
                                {
                                  if (item6.id == id)
                                  {
                                    parent = item.title;
                                    break;
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return parent;
}
```

Example JSON Structure:

Given the ID: 239108139 return the Parent Title (I'm Root)

```
[
  {
    "id": "237109438",
    "title": "I'm Root",
    "children": {
      "page": {
        "results": [
          {
            "id": "236978371",
            "title": "abc",
            "children": {
              "page": {
                "results": [
                  {
                    "id": "236945706",
                    "title": "1234",
                    "children": {
                      "page": {
                        "results": [

                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "239108139",
                    "title": "456",
                    "children": {
                      "page": {
                        "results": [

                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  At a glance it looks like the biggest problem would be that the result of the recursive call to `Fn` is ignored.  You'd probably want to `return` that result.  But doing that within a loop means it would return on the first matching iteration.  What exactly should this method be returning?  What's the data structure over which you're recursing and what are you trying to pull from that data structure?

Comment: Thanks David! Updated with JSON structure and example

Comment: Inside the if-statement, where you call `Fn` recursively, what happens to the returned value (technically I know what happens to it, I'm basically asking if you have considered that you need to *use* the returned value for something)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this returns the given Ids title, i need the root parents title. so in my JSON ID 239108139 return Title "I'm Root"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work out?

```
private string GetParent(WorkflowHierarchy.Rootobject root, string id)
{
    foreach (var item in root.results)
    {
        if (ContainsId(item, id)) return item.title;
    }

    return null;
}

private bool ContainsId(WorkflowHierarchy.Result item, string id)
{
    if (item.id == id) return true;
    if (item.children == null) return false;

    foreach (var child in item.children.page.results)
    {
        if (ContainsId(child, id)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you could call:

```
var title = GetParent(workFlowHierarchy, "239108139");
```

Answer (score 1):

You code looks like **B**readth **F**irst **S**earch (**BFS**) implementation. If it's your case you can try

```
private string Fn(WorkflowHierarchy.Rootobject workFlowHierarchy, string id) {
  //TODO: Put the right type (type of workFlowHierarchy.results item) 
  Queue<MyItemType> agenda = new Queue<MyItemType>();

  //TODO: Put the right type (type of workFlowHierarchy.results item) 
  HashSet<MyItemType> completed = new HashSet<MyItemType>(); 

  foreach (var item in workFlowHierarchy.results)
    agenda.Enqueue(item); 

  while (agenda.Count > 0) {
    var item = agenda.Dequeue();

    if (!completed.Add(item))
      continue;

    if (item.id == id)
      return item.Parent.title;

    foreach (var child in item.children.page.results)
      if (!completed.Contains(child))
        agenda.Enqueue(child);
  };

  return string.Empty;   
}
```

Comment: this seems close! does this go infinitely deep though? that's what i need

Comment: @aherrick: yes, it'll go infinitely deep if required generation after generation (children, then children of the children, then children of the children of the children etc.)

Comment: In testing, my agenda queue keeps growing infinitely and never reducing. Also, this will just get me the the given items title, i need to find the root parents title (see JSON).

Comment: @aherrick: it seems, that your gragh has *loops*. In this case we have to put additional test for completion. Please, see my edit

Comment: this returns the given Ids title, i need the root parents title. so in my JSON ID 239108139 return Title "I'm Root"

Comment: @aherrick: Don't you want to return `return item.Parent.title;` instead of `return item.title;`?